# What are some methods to know when a MainScreen will appear?

Tags: view, blackberry

I'm working on a blackberry application with navigation through multiple screens. Is there a way to know when a `MainScreen` becomes visible like the `viewWillAppear` method in iOS when I pop one `MainScreen` and go to a `MainScreen` that already exists on the view stack?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override protected  void onExposed() in your  main screen class and it will be invoked when this screen is revealed by a screen getting popped off the display stack.

Comment: See if you have time for another question I've asked- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325140/bb-autocompletefield-events-are-not-being-handled