# BB AutoCompleteField events are not being handled

Tags: search, blackberry, listener

I've added the to the `MainScreen` and the class implements `FieldChangeListener`. The problem is that it handles when I enter text and press the key but not when I delete text and then press the key. Here's how I've added it:

```
/// search bar
    BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
    String[] terms = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"};
    filterList.addDataSet(1,terms,"search",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
    autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
        public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
            if(type == SELECT_ENTER || type == SELECT_TRACKBALL_CLICK || type == SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK)
                setListView();
        }
   };
//----------------over-ridden method-----------------
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    if(field == topBar.getField(0)){
    // do something
    }
    else if(field == topBar.getField(1)){
    // do something
    }
    else if(field == topBar.getField(2)){
    //do something      
    }
    else if(field == autoCompleteField){
        setListView();//debugger never reaches here!
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Final solution was as simple as following-

```
autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            setListView();
        }
   };
```

Comment: i think you forgot to add autoCompleteField.setChangeListener(this);

Comment: nope...rather I removed it because, as @Arhimed has pointed out, `AutoCompleteField` already listens for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question you would like to get notified when the field becomes empty. If this is what you need you can point your attention to `AutoCompleteField.fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`. It is `Executed whenever the text in the field changes`. So you could override it and check if the text is an empty string and then fire your custom action.

BTW, in this case I think you should not call this:

```
autoCompleteField.setChangeListener(this);
```

because `AutoCompleteField` implements `FieldChangeListener` and it already listens for itself in `AutoCompleteField.fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`.

Comment: I removed `autoCompleteField.setChangeListener(this);`- you're right! I have other fields that implement `FieldChangeListener` so I was listening to it along with the other buttons in the over-ridden `fieldChanged(Field field, int context)` method but weirdly it didn't work! I've added this in the question

Comment: @tipycalFlow: from your comment I am still in doubt whether you fixed it or not. :)

Comment: @tipycalFlow: Have you tried overriding `AutoCompleteField.fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`? So you could override it and check if the text is an empty string and then fire your custom action.

Comment: Here's [another link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/FieldChangeListener-for-AutoCompleteField-s-does-not-work-issue/td-p/1360807) to a similar problem.