# Blackberry custom Field drawBitmap doesn't use entire space

Tags: blackberry, bitmap

I'm drawing a `Bitmap` as a background for a custom field but it doesn't draw the bitmap in the entire field's area. I've resized the image too but it always leaves out some space to the right and bottom. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here's some code for painting:

```
public int getPreferredWidth(){
    return phoneWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight(){
    return cellHeight;
}

protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    Bitmap img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cell_bg.png");        
    img.scaleInto(new Bitmap(phoneWidth, cellHeight), Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);//or other scaling methods
    g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight, img, 0, 0);//draw background
//other steps
}
```

It works fine if I set the `Background` as follows-

```
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cell_bg.png"),0,0,Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT);
this.setBackground(bg);
```

but this way, the background image is not visible `onFocus`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try to take the height and width of the device by Display.getHeight() and Display.getWidth() methode..

Comment: variable `phoneWidth` was calculated as `Display.getWidth()` so that's not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you've used `scaleInto()` incorrectly.

Try it like this:

```
Bitmap img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cell_bg.png");
Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(phoneWidth, cellHeight);         
img.scaleInto(scaled, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);//or other scaling methods
g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight, scaled, 0, 0);// here draw the scaled image(You here draw the old one)
```

the `scaled` bitmap image is given as output, **NOT** the original image .

Comment: check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325140/bb-autocompletefield-events-are-not-being-handled) too

Answer (score 1):

create an encoded image then pass this encoded image to function scaleImage()

```
EncodedImage ei = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("res/helpscreen.png");   
        EncodedImage ei1= scaleImage(ei,Graphics.getScreenWidth(),Graphics.getScreenHeight());  


  public EncodedImage scaleImage(EncodedImage source, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight) 
    {  
        int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getWidth());  
        int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredWidth);  
        int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);  
        int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getHeight());  
        int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredHeight);  
        int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);  
        return source.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);  
    }
```

then get this bitmap

```
 BitmapField logoBitmap = new BitmapField(ei1.getBitmap());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to scale the image in your code:

```
  private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String imageName, int width, int height)
  {
      try { 
          EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(imageName);
          int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
          int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());
          int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
          int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);
          int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);
          int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);
          image = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
          return image.getBitmap();
      } catch(Exception e) {
          return null; // unable to resize the image
      }    
  }
```